# ERROR - DateTime Object ( [date] => 2019-10-17 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC )

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

Al imprimir el dato me sale lo siguiente:

> DateTime Object  ( [date] => 2019-10-17 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC )

No es el resultado que espero, si me imprime la fecha, el problema es todo lo demás, solo quisiera el dato que registraron que en este caso seria "2019-10-17 00:00:00.000" en la base de datos es un dato tipo datetime, no se bien que es lo que debo hacer.

Mi cogido esta así:

```
echo"<TD class='td center'> "; date (print_r( $fila ["FECHA"])); echo"</TD>";
```

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($fila);` ? Y me parece que no debería haber espacio en blanco entre `$fila` y `[` Y, si es un objeto `DateTime` debes usar `format`  para mostrar la fecha. Por ejemplo: `echo $fila["FECHA"]->format('Y-m-d');` eso suponiendo que sea un objeto lo que haya ahí. Sería importante ver la salida del `var_dump`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al parecer en **`$fila["FECHA"]`** hay un objeto **`DateTime`**, de ser así, debes usar el [método **`format`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php) para obtener la fecha, y dejar de usar **`date()`** para crear una fecha de un objeto que ya de por sí es una fecha.

Por ejemplo, esto debería funcionar:

```
echo "<TD class=\"td center\">".$fila["FECHA"]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."</TD>";
```

[En la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) está explicado lo que significa cada letra que se podría usar en **`format`**. Para este caso he usado:

- `Y` para el año en 4 dígitos,
- `m` para el mes en dos dígitos,
- `d` para el día en dos dígitos,
- `H` para la hora formato 24,
- `i` para los minutos en dos dígitos y
- `s` para los segundos en dos dígitos.

Answer (score 0):

Si sabes que ese valor en específico es un objeto DateTime, puedes hacer uso de las funcionalidades de la misma, como dice [esta parte de la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) de PHP.

Así que solo tendrías que hacer algo como esto:

```
$date = $fila['FECHA'];

$date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:m:s.u');

var_dump($date); //Debería darte la fecha 2019-10-17 00:00:00.000 siendo un string
```